# Elasticsearch + Tire not ignore accents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying everything to solve this issue.

I have a simple app rails with a search. The search is working fine when I search something with accents, but if I search the word without accents my results is empty.

I read the documentations of Tire and Elasticsearch, but I don't know what's happening

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :_id, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do
      query { string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:q].present?
    end
  end
end
```

Bellow I tried to use asciifolding but it didn´t work.

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :user_id

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  tire.settings :index => {
      :analysis => {
          :analyzer => {
              :index_analyzer => {
                  :tokenizer => "whitespace",
                  :filter => ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball"]
              },
              :search_analyzer => {
                  :tokenizer => "whitespace",
                  :filter => ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball"]
              }
          },
          :filter => {
              :snowball => {
                  :type => "snowball",
                  :language => "Portuguese"
              }
          }
      }
  }

  mapping do
    indexes :_id, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do
      query { string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:q].present?
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Sense on Chrome to test, mapping and all config is OK!

What's happening???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the analyzer you specify in your index. You are currently using the "snowball" analyzer for your title and description which does not perform asciifolding:

```
mapping do
  indexes :_id, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
  indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
end
```

Do this instead

```
mapping do
  indexes :_id, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :title, analyzer: :index_analyzer, boost: 100
  indexes :description, analyzer: :index_analyzer
end
```

Assuming you want the query_analyzer. Then when you want to search, use the other analyzer:

```
tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do
  query { string params[:q], 
          analyzer: :search_analyzer, 
          default_operator: "AND" } if params[:q].present?
end
```